# $17^{2x} = 4^x$ Answer as exact value

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

This is what I've done so far:

$\log17^{2x} = \log4^{x} \\
(2x) \log17 = (x) \log4 \\
(2x) \log17 - (x) \log4 = 0 \\
x(\log17^2+ \log4) =0$

$x = 0$

Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).  In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *"Is $x=0$ the only solution for $17^{2x}=4^x$?"* is much more useful for other users than the current title.
From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader. You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Just as advice, try improve some aspect of your questions, like as said the previous user the formatting, or well showing more effort in your calculations. Or writing  your question in the body of your posts. I hope don't disturb with my advices. (+1), and good luck.

Comment: ok sorry @SimplyBeautifulArt I didn't realize my question would upset you so much... I just wanted to know if others could obtain x = 0 when doing the question and I got my answer from those who answered below... So, sorry if my asking if an answer is correct doesn't meet your standards for this forum but I needed help, so, excuse me.

Comment: @EvangelineStudzinski Its not so much as I've been upset.  But it is the case that this is not [a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ).  It has [previously been brought to your attention](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358012/find-equation-of-line-intersecting-point#comment4857416_2358012) that this does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question.

Comment: repeating my first comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.  Saying you know nothing does not cut it, for if you truly knew nothing, you shouldn't be asking about this question and should instead refer back to notes and your teacher

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).  To write multiple lines in one block, use `\\ `, and to write common functions, use `\log` or `\sin` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's $$\left(\frac{289}{4}\right)^x=1$$
or $x=0$.

Comment: OKay, yes you're correct. the point of intersection is (0,1)

Answer (score 2):

For a different approach, take natural logs of both sides:

$$2x\ln(17)=x\ln (4)$$

Subtracting and factoring:

$$(2\ln(17) - \ln(4))x = 0,$$

which is only possible if $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The aim with solving equations analytically is to write $0$ as a product of factors containing powers of $x$. So $2x(\log(17)-\log(2))=0$. Now it's clear there is only one solution, $x=0$ as $2\log(17/2)$ is a non zero constant.